# How to profile the number of global memory transactions without using uncached_global_load_transaction option in cuda?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I would like to profile the number of global memory transactions on GTX480. However, the uncached_global_load_transaction option doesn't help as the output for that field is always 0. Is there any other way to do it? For example, can I enable other counters and calculate the number of transactions based on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global memory is a virtual address space. Data can reside in device memory or pinned system memory. For Compute Capability 2.x devices you can calculate the hierarchy as follows:

SM to L1C Global Load Transactions

- cache transactions are 128B
- `sm2l1c_global_load_transactions = l1_global_load_hit + l1_global_load_miss`

SM to L2C Global Load Transactions

- SM uncached global transactions or L1 cache misses to L2 are in 32B transactions.
- `sm2l2c_global_load_transactions = (l1_global_load_miss * 4) + uncached_global_load_transaction`

The CUDA Profiler does not expose counters for global_atomic, global_atomic_cas, and global_red operations.

The CUDA Profiler does not expose counters to show data from L2 to system memory or to device memory based upon global vs. local. You can get the bandwidth to L2 and the bandwidth to system memory (over PCIe) or device memory (dram) using the following counters:

L2 Transactions

- L2 queries are 32B
- Depending on the version of CUDA profiler this includes reads from one or more of hte following sources to the L2: SM L1 (local, global, atom, surface), TEX cache, constant cache, instruction cache, MMU, copy engine, ...
- `l2_read_transactions = sum(l2_subp{0,1}_read_sector_queries)`

Device Memory (FB, DRAM)

- Read bandwidth to DRAM is from L2 misses and ECC (if enabled)
- FB queries are 32B
- `fb_read_transactions = sum(fb_supb{0,1}_read_sectors)`

The calculation for global stores, local load/store, and L2 to system memory follow similar patterns.

For more information see the [CUPTI User's Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUPTI_Users_Guide.pdf) section Event Reference - Compute Capability 2.x. These string names should work with recent drivers using the CUDA Profiler, Visual Profiler, nvprof (5.0), and CUPTI API.

If you are using CUDA 5.0 nvprof command `nvprof --query-events` will list all events available on your installed device.

Comment: This is only the transaction count for SM to L1 for cached global accesses. If you need me to further expand on the answer for other types of transactions please reply and I'll expand the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it is not what I need. I am only interested in global memory transactions, so l1 hits are not of concern.